# updating one sqlite file from multiple places

Tags: ios, sqlite, dropbox

Am creating an app for ios with data stored in sqlite db.

I created the db using firefox sqlite addon,and populating the fields using the same addon, the db has a table with some 1500 rows and has nearly 10 columns, which has to filled with text. since its proving tedious, am updating fields from top and my friend from bottom..

we tried using same file shared in dropbox, but its not working well, when we both update the tables at the same time..

can we create two files? and merge later?

how can i merge these two sqlite files ?

I tried attaching the file in the firefox addon, and it seems we can copy a table from attached db to main db. but while copying it asks us to create new table..

cant we insert data into particular field ranges into existing table ?

any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, spammy browser is spammy.

Answer (score 0):

Fill out the data in two *different* databases, `one.db` and `two.db`.

Then, when you're finished, open the first one, and [attach](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) the other:

```
ATTACH 'two.db' AS two;
```

Then copy all the records into the corresponding table in the first DB:

```
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM two.mytable;
```

Comment: INSERT INTO mytable SELECT mycolumn FROM two.mytable;  when am trying to copy data from one column its giving this error ---------->    SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: INSERT INTO mytable SELECT myColumn1 FROM two.db; [ table mytable has 12 columns but 1 values were supplied ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Comment: INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM two.mytable;  am getting no errors, but the data is not getting copied .. am doing this in firefox addon..even if i click refresh button or reload the the db, am seeing no changes..

Comment: Works for me. Check how many records there are: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM two.mytable;`